# This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, browser

How to load script without error This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources ?  site with https not working.

```
<iframe src="http://services.norq.am:8081/gorc/Gorcatu/IsertPagesGortsatu/for_empl.asp" width="650" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Comment: Due to security concern browser will not allow contents to load directly from a https site whose certificates are not verified/certified. You need to explicitly allow content from such sites or you can allow them through changing setting of browsers by adding those sites in trusted sites list

Comment: And How to adding those sites in trusted sites list with php or js code?

Comment: SSL Certificates need to be issued from a trusted Certificate Authority. Browsers, operating systems, and mobile devices maintain list of trusted CA root certificates. if it is not trusted the browser will present untrusted error messages to the end user.  As i am aware, JS or php will not have an access to security setting in browser. User needs to do it manually. So solution is to make sure you are using trused certificates while setting your https

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 'http' to 'https' so you should have:

```
<iframe src="https://services.norq.am:8081/gorc/Gorcatu/IsertPagesGortsatu/for_empl.asp" width="650" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
```

Comment: In that case that site isn't using HTTPS, in which case if you try and get information from it (like a script) it won't be secure